# Is there any easy way of making able to select from DBGrid?

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, tdbgrid

Is there any easy way of making able to select from DBGrid just like selecting range in excell file?

Comment: There is no (easy) way AFAIK. For start, I'd process OnCellClick/OnMouseUp/OnDrawDataCell

Comment: Depends on what you mean by range. You can select a range of records by setting the gridoptions dgMultiselect and dgRowSelect which will allow you to select a range of records and then perform some kind of operation on them

Comment: I am sure this is possible, but before I start writing a DBGrid descendant for you, what use would it serve?

Comment: I want to make it possible to copy records from dbgrid to excel file in my application.The user will enter some input value, and get table of records. Then he will copy these records to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGridOption
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid.SelectedRows
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.SelectedField
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.SelectedIndex

It seems you can have any number of ROWS selected using `dgMultiSelect` option.

However for the columns your choice is between select nothing, select single, or select the whole row (using `dgRowSelect`) and there is no option to select few of those.

I think you'd try your chances using `VirtualTreeView` in Report (ListView) mode, though it would need wrting some code